# Every time console.log(Last_Aceessed_Time) which is set to Date.now(), it shows different time, even that I didn't modify it

Tags: javascript, typescript, dictionary, date, caching

Language: JavaScript;

Environment: Code Sand Box,

So, I am implementing a basic cache in JavaScript which have two method:

- `get()` for 1. read the value of a key; 2. after read it update its `Last_Accessed_Time`.
- `put()` for 1. create a new node if the key doesn't exist using build-in method `set()`; 2. update the node with new data.

---

The problem I have is that when I testing my cache, every time I put a new value in a specific node, the last accessed time of all node was updated.

I have tried to google it but I couldn't find someone have the similar problem as I have. So I tried to ask Chat-GPT, and it said that may be is the problem of `console.log()` which will log the shadow reference of the `Last_Accessed_Time`, and I have to log it with `Json.parse()`.

I have to admit that I have no idea what GPT is talking about, So I google it again but still couldn't find any clue of my problem. After all that I start thinking may be it is a bug in Code Sand Box (please forgive my naivety), and I run my code in VScode and I got the same result: I change one key's value, I update all keys's last accessed time unintentionally.

I think the problem is that I lack of JavaScript and programming's fundamental knowledge. I am working on it. It is a long run. So right now can someone give me some enlightenment?

And please forgive my poor English and potentially wrong spelling, being a person who used to speak Chinese and Japanese learning English with programming altogether really takes time to become more accurate, even with the basic rules.

Code:

```js
class CacheGenerator {

  constructor(capacity) {
    this.capacity = capacity;
    this.cache = new Map();
  }

  get(key) {
    let node = this.cache.get(key);
    if (node) {
      node.last_Accessed_Time = Date.now();
      return node.value;
    }
    return -1;
  }

  put(key, value, weight) {
    if (this.capacity <= 0) {
      return;
    }

    if (this.cache.has(key)) {
      let node = this.cache.get(key);
      node.value = value;
      node.weight = weight;
      node.last_Accessed_Time = Date.now();
      return;
    }

    if (this.cache.size >= this.capacity) {
      let minScore = Infinity;
      let minKey = null;


      for (let [k, v] of this.cache) {
        let score =
          v.weight / (Math.log(Date.now() - v.last_Accessed_Time + 1) + 1);

        if (score < minScore) {
          minScore = score;
          minKey = k;
        }
      }
      this.cache.delete(minKey);
    }
    let node = {
      value,
      weight,
      last_Accessed_Time: Date.now()
    };
    this.cache.set(key, node);
  }
}

// Testing
const cache = new CacheGenerator(3);

cache.put("key1", "hokaido", 10);
cache.put("key2", "tokyo", 20);
cache.put("key3", "osaka", 30);
cache.put("key1", "sapporo", 40); // Reset key1 with new value.
console.log(Array.from(cache.cache.entries()));; // All key's last accessed time got update.
```

Comment: All four `put`s run fast so `Date.now()` is the same for all the entries.

Comment: @RobG Sorry about that, I have corrected it to JavaScript. As you can see, All `Last_Accessed_Time` are the same, even I only change `"key1"`.

Comment: @RameshReddy But why is that I only modified one key's value and other's last accessed time is changed too?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be writing the Last_Accessed_Time time over again.
This code will make it clear that it is working as expected.
---
cache.put("key1", "hokaido", 10);
setTimeout(() => {
  cache.put("key2", "tokyo", 20);
  cache.put("key3", "osaka", 30);
  console.log(Array.from(cache.cache.entries())); // All key's last accessed time got update.
}, 5000);
console.log(Array.from(cache.cache.entries())); // All key's last accessed time got update.

Comment: As Dovid says, separate the calls with *setTimeout* or similar, @RameshReddy has your answer

Comment: @ShimizuYang The time of other entries is not changed after the last `put`. They will have the same value even if you remove the last `put`. As I said, it is because `Date.now()` returns the same value when called fast.